# Data being hidden when importing data from a website via script

Tags: google-apps-script, web-scraping, google-sheets

When the data is copied, in theory it should appear `-` or `X:Y Half time results: Z:A`, but some values as shown below are hidden, I would like to know what is wrong with the script that is doing this happen and how the script has to stay so that it doesn't happen anymore. Only the values appear when there is a V mark (in green color) together to the result of the game.

**SITE:**
[image]

**CURRENT RESULTS:**
[image]

**EXPECTED RESULTS:**
[image]

**THE COLUMN THAT IS MISSING DATA TO COLLECT IS THIS:**
[image]

```
function sample(placeOfUrl) {
  // Retrieve URL.
  var baseUrl = "http://old.statarea.com/predictions.php";
  var res1 = UrlFetchApp.fetch(baseUrl);
  if (res1.getResponseCode() != 200) throw new Erro("URL cannot be used.");
  const from = '<td style="padding-top: 10px; text-align: center;">';
  const to = '&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>';
  const htmlData1 = (from + Parser.data(res1.getContentText()).from(from).to(to).build() + to).replace(/\&nbsp;/g, "");
  const xmlRoot = XmlService.parse(htmlData1).getRootElement();
  const c = xmlRoot.getChildren()[placeOfUrl - 1];
  if (!c) return;
  const url = c.getAttribute("href").getValue();

  // Parse HTML data.
  const res2 = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  if (res2.getResponseCode() != 200) throw new Erro("URL for retrieving data cannot be used.");
  const htmlData2 = res2.getContentText();
  const parsedData1 = Parser.data(htmlData2).from('<table class="style_1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="918" border="0">').to('</table>').build();
  const parsedData2 = Parser.data(parsedData1).from("<tr>").to("</tr>").iterate();
  const data = parsedData2
    .filter(function(e) {return /^<td width="35" align="center">/.test(e)})
    .map(function(e) {return "<content>" + e.match(/<td.+?\/td>/g).map(function(f) {return f.replace(/\&nbsp\;|<div.+?>|<\/div>|<img.+?>|<input.+?>|\&team_guest|<\/h.+?>|\&/g, "")}).join("") + "</content>"})
    .join("");
  const xmlRootContent = XmlService.parse("<root>" + data + "</root>").getRootElement();

  // Retrieve result values.
  const content = xmlRootContent.getChildren();
  const values = content.reduce((ar1, e) => {
    const temp = e.getChildren().reduce((ar2, f, j) => {
      if (f) {
        if (f.getChild("a")) {
          const t = f.getChild("a").getValue()
          if (t) ar2.push(t);
        } else {
          if (f.getAttribute("style")) {
            const v = f.getValue();
            if (v && [5, 6, 7, 8, 15].includes(j)) {
              ar2.push(v);
            }
          }
        }
      }
      return ar2;
    }, []);
    ar1.push(temp);
    return ar1;
  }, []);

  return values;
}
```

LINK TO SPREADSHEET:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ZdU05slyWXHeOVnoRzhpUNCzb8lBuAsJlVys2bmdh20/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand about your issue. Because now, only 4 values of `X:Y Half time results: Z:A` are included in the HTML retrieved from the URL. Can I ask you about the relationship between this situation and your issue? And also, can I ask you about your goal?

Comment: Good night my friend, I just added the part called **expected results** to the question, it shows exactly what is missing to appear in the spreadsheet. I don't know why but it is only copying the values when there is that green V in the result. It is missing to copy the ```-``` and the other results when there is no green V.

Comment: I only see that you are returning values here but there's nothing about how they get displayed so it's hard to deal with the question how and where they might be hidden.

Comment: Cooper, I added in the question the image that shows which column of data is not collecting the data in a complete way, in case I misunderstood what you need, I'm sorry, my English is flawed.

Comment: Okay this issue isn't that the values are hidden in the final display it's just that they are not being collected. Is that correct?

Comment: That's correct Cooper!

Comment: Can you look in the file to see if the data is actually in there or not?

Comment: ```<td width="40" align="center">-</td>```

Comment: ```<span class="tip">Half time results: 0:0</span>```

Comment: Thank you for replying. You want to use the value of `-` when `Half time results:` is not included. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: In fact these values already exist in the column, as the image shows on the website: http://old.statarea.com/predictions.php, but it is not returning

Comment: I proposed a modification point as an answer. But I'm not sure whether that is the direction you expect. So it that was not the direction you expect, I apologize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to achieve your goal, for example, how about modifying `values` as follows?

#### From:

```
const values = content.reduce((ar1, e) => {
  const temp = e.getChildren().reduce((ar2, f, j) => {
    if (f) {
      if (f.getChild("a")) {
        const t = f.getChild("a").getValue()
        if (t) ar2.push(t);
      } else {
        if (f.getAttribute("style")) {
          const v = f.getValue();
          if (v && [5, 6, 7, 8, 15].includes(j)) {
            ar2.push(v);
          }
        }
      }
    }
    return ar2;
  }, []);
  ar1.push(temp);
  return ar1;
}, []);
```

#### To:

```
const values = content.reduce((ar1, e) => {
  const temp = e.getChildren().reduce((ar2, f, j) => {
    if (f) {
      if (f.getChild("a")) {
        const t = f.getChild("a").getValue();
        if (t) ar2.push(t);
      } else if (f.getChild("span")) {
        ar2.push(f.getValue());
      } else {
        const v = f.getValue();
        if (v && [5, 6, 7, 8, 15].includes(j)) {
          ar2.push(v);
        }
      }
    }
    return ar2;
  }, []);
  ar1.push(temp);
  return ar1;
}, []);
```

Comment: The ```-``` are showing, but the results that do not have a green V still do not return... Like in: ```Louisville City FC -  Saint Louis FC```

Comment: PlaceOfUrl - ```=sample(4)``` - Link to Spreadsheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ZdU05slyWXHeOVnoRzhpUNCzb8lBuAsJlVys2bmdh20/edit?usp=sharing - Link to Script: https://script.google.com/d/1-DeC2h_455TyEdzuEd-Yh7gIztFIB3psV7_ZdejHsXMBdlmrN9XrdgC-/edit?mid=ACjPJvFTZt8dFD2CLifOKunMCdPQY23q4nbspzyBT-5KL3ghwMg0vcrIeDQiPBcfpGELJL4vV2GTK_EhsQt83RnHvmzOTY5HHZ_MW0kmUz-0lrBmCfvMLEscnRTjz-WtqknIXnTR9VzL8Gg&uiv=2

Comment: @Brondby IF Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. About `Louisville City FC -  Saint Louis FC`, in your original script, the value has not been retrieved. How about this?

Comment: I looked here now, updated the script, but the result of it still doesn't appear. In theory it would have to appear: ```0:0Half time results: 0:1``` but appears ```-```

Comment: @Brondby IF Thank you for replying. I could understand about what you want to do. So I updated my answer. Could you please confirm it? In that case, please modify your original script as above. In this case, my 1st modification is not required. `values` are directly created.

Comment: Mate, return error: ```ReferenceError: content is not defined (linha 27).``` line 27: ```const values = content.reduce((ar1, e) => {```

Comment: @Brondby IF Sorry. One line had added when I copied your original script. I updated it.

Comment: @Brondby IF By the way, now I tested your original script like `=sample(4)`, 36 rows are retrieved. I thought that the returned values might be changed. How about this?

Comment: In the end the correct thing would be: `` `return values;` ``? Because mine is giving error so far.

Comment: @Brondby IF Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, I cannot replicate your current situation. So can you provide your current script for replicating your issue? Because in my environment, no error occurs. I deeply apologize for this.

Comment: Yes, I certainly share without problems:  Link to Script: https://script.google.com/d/1-DeC2h_455TyEdzuEd-Yh7gIztFIB3psV7_ZdejHsXMBdlmrN9XrdgC-/edit?mid=ACjPJvFTZt8dFD2CLifOKunMCdPQY23q4nbspzyBT-5KL3ghwMg0vcrIeDQiPBcfpGELJL4vV2GTK_EhsQt83RnHvmzOTY5HHZ_MW0kmUz-0lrBmCfvMLEscnRTjz-WtqknIXnTR9VzL8Gg&uiv=2

Comment: @Brondby IF Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. I replied `Sorry. One line had added when I copied your original script. I updated it.`. But it seems that you couldn't understand about it. I deeply apologize for this. In your current script, `const content = xmlRootContent.getChildren();` is not included. By this, the error occurs. Please put it before `const values = content.reduce((ar1, e) => {` and test it again.

Comment: Cool mate! Thats perfect now! Thanks!

Comment: @Brondby IF Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.